# What's the word when you're describing how someone is, how their day was, etc.

Tags: single-word-requests

EG, "I didn't even bother with the ***_***."

I can't seem to find the word for it! (I think it ends in 'ties' like 'profanities' lol

Comment: Are you thinking of (exchanging) *pleasantries?*

Comment: @Autoresponder I'll +1 that if you give it as an answer; it's a better answer than the one I gave.

Comment: 'Profanities'! And they say that humour is dead.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you are speaking of *formalities*, as the word is used of *phatic* speech.

Edit: *Formalities* refer to such *pleasantries* that are dictated by convention or tradition, and it also covers some other practices, making it imprecise. Autoresponder is on the button with *pleasantries* as the perfect word to use here, and should get the tick if they offer it as an answer.

Comment: @Autoresponder That's a helpful addition perhaps (I certainly intended it as such), but I still think you have the mot juste with *pleasantries*.